# Can java.awt.Desktop open a file with administrator privilege?

Tags: java, batch-file

I tried to open a file using `Desktop` class, this is my code:

```
try{
    //filePath is an instance String variable
    desktop.open(new File(filePath));
}catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

But the problem here the file must be opened with administrator then it'll be run.

For example; if we have this command

> netsh wlan start hostednetwork

I saved it in `netsh.bat` file, when I am opening this file, it'll be run automatically, but unfortunately; windows needs administrator privilege to run this command.

I think opening this file (`neths.bat`) as *administrator* solves the problem.

But ***How to do it?***, is the question here.

Thanks

Comment: Consider running the Java app as administrator?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: Not a Java app, any app's on the computer that needs a permission. Sorry for the late comment :)

Comment: There is no way in java to run as administrator.
If it is possible,then plz share it.
I am also in search of the way to run command prompt with admin privilage.

Comment: Windows comes with a utility named `runas.exe`, java can spawn this.  Or use the Java Native Interface to call `CreateProcessAsUser`.  Or set an environment variable triggering a compatibility shim that forces elevation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) method denies read access to the file, or it denies the AWTPermission("showWindowWithoutWarningBanner") permission, or the calling thread is not allowed to create a subprocess

Ex.

```
if(file.canRead()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
}
```

Or

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("netsh.bat");
pb.directory(new File(currentDir + "\\com\\project"));
Process p = pb.start();
int status = p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't helped, it won't run.